# How do I add a space to a field that may or may not return multiple values?

Tags: oraclereports

I am using Oracle Reports Builder 10.1.2.0.2. I have a part of a query that may return multiple values (which is fine, I want all the values to display). My issue is the spacing between the values when they come into the field. I get something like this:

```
Value1Value2Value3 (etc)
```

What I want is for it to come out like this:

```
Value1, Value2, Value3
```

Thanks in advance for the response(s)!

Comment: @Charkins12 I'm not entirely certain how this corresponds to my issue. This link isn't for oracle reports builder, but some IBM product. If you can give me an example of how this works, that'd be great.

Comment: Found the answer! Used the LISTAGG function to add comma(s) where necessary